# Why value from variable "y" is 5? not 7?

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

first of all sorry for my bad english

so, this is my code:

```js
let x = 5
const {x: y=7} = {x}

console.log(y) // output is 5
```

but why 5? is not 7?

Comment: Actually, it is `const y = {x: 5}.x || 7`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`{x}` is shorthand for `{x: x}`. Since the value of `x` is `5`, this is equivalent to `{x: 5}`.

That means your code is equivalent to

```
const {x: y=7} = {x: 5}
```

This sets `y` to the value of the `x` property in `{x: 5}`. If there were no property, it would use the default value of `7`; but since the property does exist, its value is used, so it sets `y` to `5`.

Compare with

```
let a = 5;
const {x: y=7} = {a}
```

This will set `y` to `7` because there's no `x` property in the object.

Comment: Didn't know you could default values on objects like that.  My new fact of the day, :)

Answer (score 0):

note : equals assignment have a left to right operation
in other words... the left side takes greater precedence over the right and overrides the any value on the left

```
const{ x = y } = {x = 5}
x........ maps to..........x
y......... maps to..........5 (overriding the previous y value)
```

Also........... You can take it this way

what you simply wrote was

```
y=7
y=5
```

y=5 came last so it replaced the previous value

Comment: What previous y value is being overridden?

Comment: y=7 is what is overriden

Comment: `y=7` was never assignment, it was a default value for destructuring